# What is the purpose of the yellow wired panels on the IBM 360 Model 20?

Tags: ibm, mainframe, s360

I just finished reading a story about an [IBM 360 Model 20 rescue](https://ibms360.co.uk/?p=64), and some of the pictures caught my eye.

Specifically this one:

[image]

Searching online, led me to several more pictures, all with obviously different configurations. It seems that this panel is exposed in a way that makes changing the wiring "easy".

[image]

What is the purpose of these wiring panels?  Did changing the wiring somehow configure the operation and features of the computer?

Comment: That poor IBM 360, lost in a decrepit warehouse. The article now appears at _The Register _[Wanted: Big iron geeks to help restore IBM 360 mainframe rescued from defunct German factory by other big iron geeks](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/05/21/ibm_360_mainframe_restoration_project/): Why random plans made in pub shouldn't always be acted upon_ . "They chanced upon a listing for an IBM 360 Model 20 or, as the German ad put it, "a relatively rare plant Puma Computer IBM 2020 probably from the 1980s in red". Yeah, there is a photo of a Puma apparel decal on the machine.

Comment: This article generated some buzz on slashdot. I don't think this is authoritative enough to post as an answer, but a user there mentions "IBM was big on [wire-wrapping] as a way to customize hardware." https://slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=13991796&cid=58620992

Comment: The two answers below are correct - this is just the way the machine was built (or patched by the manufacturer) but these are not _user serviceable parts_.  However, _prior_ to programmable computers there were [_unit record machines_ with _plugboards_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugboard) - the user in those cases _did_ "program" the machines by wiring up plugboards (for some limited definition of "programming").  Different plugboards would represent different "applications" and you'd have a stack in the corner which you'd swap in and out for payroll tasks, acct's payable tasks, etc.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the yellow wired panels

It's the backplane, simply the wiring of the machine.

> on the IBM 360 Model 20?

Not just there, but next to every mainframe was made that way. Depending on planned (and ordered) production run some would get printed boards, but usually all wiring was done as wire-wrap. The -20 was sold in quite high numbers and above fotos show a somewhat late model. But even here not all routing was done on a PCB, but as wirewrap.

Being trained on this technology in the late 70s, I still remember countless hours spend in debugging and adding of patches.

Comment: So the wiring really wasn't meant to be changed at all?  Are the differences between the photos just due to how the wires were routed on that particular unit, or possibly different production runs with different component layouts?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I don't think there are any significant differences between the wiring in the two photos. In the first photo you are looking down on the back plane from above. In the second we are looking at it from an angle between the side and straight on.

Comment: The wiring wasn’t supposed to be changed by end-users, but it was common for service technicians to patch it (often with different-coloured wires).

Comment: The biggest difference in the wiring I see is what would be the top-left panel.  In the top picture, the main "bus" of wires goes all the way up, and makes a hard left turn.  In the 2nd picture, the "bus" splits just above the topmost "bridge" connection between panels, forming a Y shape.  The top picture also contains several diagonally run wires that are not present on bottom picture.

Comment: There are several sources for differences. Starting with patches to increase stability (sometimes you will even find resistors or capacitors added in backplane wiring) made already in production, as well as later by service personal, over patches to add functionality (usually just a few wires, as more often than not additional hardware was build in but not activated) all the way to upgrades from one model to another (as far as the basic setup allowed). Not to mention changes to add more memory, beyond what a certain model originally supported. so yes, much changes happened, but never by users.

Comment: [Gardner-Denver wirewrap machine](https://www.computerhistory.org/revolution/artifact/331/1903)

Comment: Not just mainframes, by the way. DEC minicomputers had wirewrapped backplanes until quite late in the life of the product line.

Comment: And it became so much easier with the System/370, as a lot of this stuff disappeared.

Comment: @BradleyUffner: I'd be completely unsurprised if the same production runs had wiring that looked different - same topology, pin A to pin B, but different routing of the wire depending on the technician doing the soldering, some tucking a bunch  along corners, some connecting in a straight line, some wires installed earlier (and so passing below) others than elsewhere...

Comment: The wires isn't soldered - it is wire-wrapping ie the wire is slightly stretched around the wire-wrap posts which is rectangular with sharp corners so the corner will cut thru the insulation and due to the wire's tiny stretch get a good and permanent grip in the copper.

Comment: @SF.: I would think that most places that mass-produced wire wrapped machines would have detailed plans as to how exactly wires should be routed for each design revision.  Leaving things up to the whims of the technician wiring it would make it very difficult to find any wiring mistakes.

Comment: @supercat There were rules how to wire depending on both connectors. They were observed by factory made wires, but as well (hopefully) by field engineers doing patches as well. Then again, these rules may have been company /factory specific, so getting company manuals may be helfpul.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I would expect that the design documents for mass-produced devices would specify the order in which all "normally-colored" wires are to be installed.  The decision of whether to connect X to Y before or after Y is connected to Z might be made arbitrarily at the design stage, but the wiring charts would specify an order, and I would think technicians would be expected to follow it so as to allow practical inspection.

Comment: @supercat ??? Not sure what you want to tell me by repeating what I said.

Comment: @supercat: Depends - how "mass-produced" it is. If there's over 1000 devices to be built, a very detailed instruction of assembly would help, by streamlining the QA process. If it's 70 devices across 5 revisions and 8 variants, preparing the exact procedure would cost more than save.

Comment: @SF. Even with just a single production unit, any professional company will design clear manufacturing documentation. Also, routing basics are independent of a machine but underlaying documents for all designs. After all, there no good in field engineers having to learn different rules for different models. Ths would only lead to chaos and problems in the field. Then again, my experience for mainframe maintenance is restricted to German companies others may try different :)

Comment: @Raffzahn: My point was that beyond the existence of design rules, I would expect that for many machines there would be a document specifying that the first wire on a peg goes to X, the second to Y, and the third to Z, eliminating any room for judgment calls on the part of the person wiring the assembly.

Comment: @supercat: for smal runs, often the person wiring the assembly is the same person who writes the assembly manual and is heavily involved in design. The prototype goes through several revisions, assembly instructions modified to adapt to hot-fixes, and under pressure of deadlines first production models following the rather messy set of instructions with a whole bunch of manual edits and corrections. Only when the initial pressure is off work on streamlining and optimizing the process and cleanup of the manual begins, while new, smarter and neater ways to achieve same result are found.

Answer (score 8):

Couldn't find much on the purpose but physically those appear to be terminals that are used for [wire-wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_wrap).  You see this application used in all manner of early electronic equipment and its used to interconnect various circuits.

IBM Service technicians (customer engineers or CEs) would be the ones to actually change these (not customer serviceable).

I'm speculating but apart from circuit interconnects this could have been used as a crude form of "microcode" changes / adjustments or feature additions.